# Elevated process in Vista does not overwrite files

Tags: c++, windows, uac

I'm trying to run elevated process, say, file_copier.exe, from another host process with ShellExecuteEx and lpVerb = "runas" on Vista. It shows UAC dialog and runs elevated, and copies files to "dangerous" folders, but it does not overwrite existing files (exe's).

I've read here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/UAC__The_Definitive_Guide.aspx that UAC does not actually overwrite existing files but stores new files in a cache of some sort. But I can't figure out (if it is the case), how to make it **actually overwrite** existing files. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which folders are you writing to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about [virtualization of file system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756960.aspx). To tell Windows that your program are aware of Windows rules you should change your [manifest file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

Add to the manifest the following text:

```
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
```

Comment: +1: It's helpful! I just want to add that `"{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"` is the GUID of Windows 8 (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848036(v=vs.85).aspx) for example)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys it was just my mistake. The code was like this:

```
ShellExecuteEx(file_copier.exe);
LaunchFreshVersionOfApplication();
```

Indeed, ShellExecuteEx returned before the file_copier.exe process finished. So the later process could not update running files. Thanks for your answer, Kirill!

Comment: Then why not give Kirill his deserved rep by giving him the checkmark?

Comment: With pleasure, but my reputation is only 9, and voting requires 15, sorry.